# How to pass an Array in a <script> from a JSP page to a Servlet

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, servlets

I try to explain quickly and in detail what I plan to do. I've the following JSP page:

JSP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <style>
        .AreaFree {
            -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #3dc21b;
            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #3dc21b;
            background-color: #44c767;
            border: 1px solid #18ab29;
            display: inline-block;
            cursor: pointer;
            color: #ffffff;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding: 15px 21px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .AreaFree:hover {
            background-color: #5cbf2a;
        }

        .AreaFree:active {
            position: relative;
        }

        .AreaOccupated {
            -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #3dc21b;
            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #3dc21b;
            background-color: #E00000;
            border: 1px solid #B00000;
            display: inline-block;
            cursor: pointer;
            color: #ffffff;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding: 15px 21px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .AreaOccupated:hover {
            background-color: #D00000;
        }

        .AreaOccupated:active {
            position: relative;
        }

        .AreaBlocked {
            -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #3dc21b;
            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #3dc21b;
            background-color: #A8A8A8;
            border: 1px solid #808080;
            display: inline-block;
            cursor: pointer;
            color: #ffffff;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding: 15px 21px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .AreaBlocked:hover {
            background-color: #989898;
        }

        .AreaBlocked:active {
            position: relative;
        }

        input.clicked {
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
 </head>

<body>
    <form action="myServlet" method="post">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" class="AreaFree" id="11" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" class="AreaFree" id="12" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" class="AreaFree" id="13" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" class="AreaFree" id="14" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" class="AreaFree" id="15" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" class="AreaFree" id="21" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" class="AreaFree" id="22" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" class="AreaFree" id="23" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" class="AreaFree" id="24" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" class="AreaFree" id="25" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <input type="hidden" id="matrix" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" value="callServlet" name="whatsend">
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>

    <script>
        var matrix = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            matrix.push(0);
        }
        // set the hidden field on init
        $('#matrix').val(matrix);
        $('input[type="button"]').on('click', function(evt) {
            var me = $(this);
            var idx = +me.attr('id'); // the + sign turns this value to a number
            if (matrix[idx] === 0) {
                matrix[idx] = 1;
                me.addClass('AreaBlocked');
            } else {
                matrix[idx] = 0;
                me.removeClass('AreaBlocked');
            }
            // update the hidden field every time a user clicks something
            $('#matrix').val(matrix);
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Principally, in the following JSP page there is a table of buttons. Each button represents an area; the user decides to click on various buttons and these change color and status (on-off). Once the user select the buttons that he wants, press the submit button and send an array called "matrix" to a servlet, that containing information on each button pressed or not (boolean 0 or 1).

That's what I do in the servlet "myServlet"

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,     HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {

        String whatsend = request.getParameter("whatsend");

        if(whatsend.equals("callServlet")){
             String matrix = request.getParameter("matrix");

        }

     }

     catch (SQLException ex) {

     }
}
```

Well, once you press the submit button the servlet is called, enters in the if block and executes the command request.getParameter, but unfortunately matrix is null. Where am I wrong? How do I move that array to this servlet? Could you kindly share the correct code? Thanks in advance, I'm sorry if I wasn't not much detailed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, the form does not send any parameter named "matrix", because there's no input with `name="matrix"`. So the first thing you have to do is to change that:

```
<input type="hidden" id="matrix" value="" />
```

into that:

```
<input type="hidden" id="matrix" name="matrix" value="" />
```

Then, you will have to consider how are you serializing the matrix. An input can only hold a value of type string (and only strings can be sent to the server) so you have to serialize the array into a string. That is usually (but not necessarily) accomplished through JSON. You would first convert the matrix to a JSON string before setting it as a value for the input:

```js
$('#matrix').val(JSON.stringify(matrix));
```

And then in the server you would have to convert it back to an array. You can use several libraries for that. Two common options are [JSON in Java](http://www.json.org/java/) and Google's [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson). The following example uses Gson and assumes that the seralized value is always an array of integers:

```java
String matrixStr = request.getParameter("matrix");
Gson gson = new Gson();
Integer[] matrix = gson.fromJson(matrixStr, Integer[].class);
```

Comment: Unfortunally I am not an expert in JavaScript, could you send me all the entire code of the pages with the problem solved? Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @Zoythrus I could, but I won't. Have you tried to modify your code according to my answer?

Comment: I cannot try to modify my code randomly, without understanding what I need to do. I've just fix my hidden     <input type="hidden" id="matrix" name="matrix" value="" /> as you said, But now I didn't understand where to insert the rest of the code you've shared.

Comment: Use `$('#matrix').val(JSON.stringify(matrix));` instead of `$('#matrix').val(matrix);`. The last snippet of code (the Java code) is meant for parsing the request into an array. It goes in the servlet.

Comment: I'm trying, but what is the library that I need to import in the servlet to use the Gson?

Comment: I've imported "json_simple-1.0.2.jar" and "gson-2.5.jar" in my library. 
In the servlet I've import these:  import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import com.google.gson.Gson; I've paste your java code and I get error. The error is:

Comment: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
                int matrix[] = gson.fromJson(matrixStr, Integer[].class);
    equality constraints: Integer[]
    upper bounds: int[],Object
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>fromJson(String,Class<T>)

Comment: @Zoythrus I'm glad that you could import the libraries.  You don't need "json_simple-1.0.2.jar", however, just the other one. As for the error, it's because you wrote `int matrix[]` instead of `Integer[] matrix`.

Comment: You're right, my mistake. Forgive me but I'm learning to use the scripts and I still have some difficulty to understand how they work. Thank you so much for helping me.

Ps. Just the last question: I correct the code with "Integer[] matrix = gson.fromJson(matrixStr, Integer[].class);", is this code correct: "int[] matrix = gson.fromJson(matrixStr, int[].class);"? I think no, because Integer is a class and int is a primitive type. So... now I have an Integer array, how could I convert it into an int array?

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't work. But I think the solution is to create an int[] array and to use .intValue() for each Integer element of the Integer array. Thank you so much again.